# How do I create a serializer that reuses a unique key of my model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest, django-serializer, unique-key

I'm using Python 3.7, Django 2.2, the Django rest framework, and pytest.  I have the following model, in which I want to re-use an existing model if it exists by its unique key ...

```py
class CoopTypeManager(models.Manager):

    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get_or_create(name=name)[0]

class CoopType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)

    objects = CoopTypeManager()
```

Then I have created the below serializer to generate this model from REST data

```
class CoopTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CoopType
        fields = ['id', 'name']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `CoopType` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return CoopType.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `CoopType` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

However, when I run the below test in which I intentionally use a name that is taken

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_coop_type_create_with_existing(self):
    """ Test coop type serizlizer model if there is already a coop type by that name """
    coop_type = CoopTypeFactory()
    serializer_data = {
        "name": coop_type.name,
    }

    serializer = CoopTypeSerializer(data=serializer_data)
    serializer.is_valid()
    print(serializer.errors)
    assert serializer.is_valid(), serializer.errors
    result = serializer.save()
    assert result.name == name
```

I get the below error

```
python manage.py test --settings=directory.test_settings
...        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/tests/test_serializers.py", line 46, in test_coop_type_create_with_existing
    assert serializer.is_valid(), serializer.errors
AssertionError: {'name': [ErrorDetail(string='coop type with this name already exists.', code='unique')]}
```

How do I construct my serializer so that I can create my model if its unique key doesn't exist, or re-use it if it does?

**Edit:** Here's the GitHub link ...

```
https://github.com/chicommons/maps/tree/master/web
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DRF validates the uniqueness of each field if is declared with `unique=True` in the model, so you have to change the model as following if you want to keep your unique contraint for the `name` field:

```py
class CoopType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)

    objects = CoopTypeManager()

    class Meta:
        # Creates a new unique constraint with the `name` field
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name'], name='coop_type_unq')]
```

Also, you have to change your serializer, if you're using a ViewSet with the default behavior, you only need to add a custom validation in the serializer.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

from .models import CoopType


class CoopTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    default_error_messages = {'name_exists': 'The name already exists'}

    class Meta:
        model = CoopType
        fields = ['id', 'name']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        validated_attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        errors = {}

        # check if the new `name` doesn't exist for other db record, this is only for updates
        if (
            self.instance  # the instance to be updated
            and 'name' in validated_attrs  # if name is in the attributes
            and self.instance.name != validated_attrs['name']  # if the name is updated
        ):
            if (
                CoopType.objects.filter(name=validated_attrs['name'])
                .exclude(id=self.instance.id)
                .exists()
            ):
                errors['name'] = self.error_messages['name_exists']

        if errors:
            raise ValidationError(errors)

        return validated_attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # get_or_create returns a tuple with (instance, boolean). The boolean is True if a new instance was created and False otherwise
        return CoopType.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)[0]
```

The `update` method was removed because is not needed.

Finally, the tests:

```py
class FactoryTest(TestCase):

    def test_coop_type_create_with_existing(self):
        """ Test coop type serializer model if there is already a coop type by that name """
        coop_type = CoopTypeFactory()
        serializer_data = {
            "name": coop_type.name,
        }

        # Creation
        serializer = CoopTypeSerializer(data=serializer_data)
        serializer.is_valid()
        self.assertTrue(serializer.is_valid(), serializer.errors)
        result = serializer.save()
        assert result.name == serializer_data['name']

        # update with no changes
        serializer = CoopTypeSerializer(coop_type, data=serializer_data)
        serializer.is_valid()
        serializer.save()
        self.assertTrue(serializer.is_valid(), serializer.errors)

        # update with the name changed
        serializer = CoopTypeSerializer(coop_type, data={'name': 'testname'})
        serializer.is_valid()
        serializer.save()
        self.assertTrue(serializer.is_valid(), serializer.errors)
        coop_type.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(coop_type.name, 'testname')
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `unique=True` key in model, Serializer will automaticly add unique validator to that field.
It’s enough to cancel the uniqueness check by writting your own `name` field directly in serializer to prevent your curent error:

```
class Ser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()  # no unique validation here

    class Meta:
        model = CoopType
        fields = ['id', 'name']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return CoopType.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)
```

Be carefull: `get_or_create` in `create` method will return tuple, not instance.

Ok, now imagine you will call it with `id` field too so you really need an `update` method.
Then you can make the following hack in `validate` method (maybe it's dirty, but it will work):

```
class Ser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # no `read_only` option (default for primary keys in `ModelSerializer`)
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    # no unique validators in charfield
    name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CoopType
        fields = ["id", "name"]

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)

        if "id" in attrs:
            try:
                self.instance = CoopType.objects.get(name=attrs["name"])
            except CoopType.DoesNotExist:
                pass

            # to prevent manual changing ids in database
            del attrs["id"]

        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return CoopType.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # you can delete that method, it will be called anyway from parent class
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

The `save` method on the serializer checks if the field `self.instance` is null or not. If there is an non-empty `self.instance`, it will call the `update` method; else - `create` method.
So if `CoopType` with name from your `serializer_data` dictionary exists - `update` method will be called. In other case you will see `create` method call.

Comment: I gave your suggestion a whirl but got the error, "AssertionError: {'id': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}".  I'm going to edit my question to include a GitHub link if that's useful.

Comment: @Dave  i've lost `required=True` in `id` field in second code snippet. I've updated that snippet in answer, check it out

Comment: Thanks.  So a clarification, you issued a warning about using "get_or_create", so I changed it to just "create", but now when I run my test, I get teh error, 'mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'test name' for key 'directory_cooptype.name''.  I would like to re-use the cooptype if one already exists by that name, but I seem to be missing how to do that.

Comment: @Dave please, show me your final serializer version and test func (maybe in gihub gist for ex.)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to not use a `ModelSerializer` but instead use a vanilla serializer.

```
class CoopTypeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, required=True, allow_blank=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `CoopType` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return CoopType.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)[0]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `CoopType` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```